# Why type parameter required before return type for static generic methods

Tags: java, generics, methods, static, generic-method

The following `noGood` method gives a compilation error because it omits the formal type parameter immediately before the return type `T`.

```
public static T noGood(T t) {
  return t;
}
```

Could somebody please help me understand that why is it required for a static generic method to have a type parameter before the return type? Is it not required for a non-static method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The type parameter (`T`) is declared when you **instantiate** the class. Thus, instance methods don't need a type argument, since it's defined by the instance.

`static` methods, on the other hand, don't belong to an instance - they belong to the class. Since there's no instance to get the type information from, it must be specified for the method itself.

Answer (score 2):

`T` wasn't defined. The order of modifiers and the return type remains the same.

```
public static <T> T noGood(T t) {
    return t;
}
```

Comment: interestingly enough, there is a use-case for this apparently useless method... it's usually called `self`...

Answer (score 2):

When you're using generic, you need to declare them, using `<>` notation

1. In a class

   ```
   public class Foo<T, U, V>{

   }
   ```
2. In a method, before the return type

   ```
   public static <T, U extends Number, V> T foo(T t) {
       U u = ..;
       ...
   }

   public static <T> int foo(T t) {
       ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is pretty standard in languages.  Even in C++:

```
template <class myType>
myType GetMax (myType a, myType b) {
    return (a>b?a:b);
}
```

You declare the type parameter above a generic function.

When its a member function of a class, it has access to the class's type parameters.  When its static it doesn't, so you need to declare them explicitly.